# why can't I talk to kubectl when a node is missing?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using RKE on some local metal instances. If I kill a node (say, unplug it), `kubectl` doesn't respond to API requests anymore. It times out after 60sec.

What should I look for? FWIW, the IP listed in `.kube/config` isn't the node that is currently dead.

```
$ time kubectl get nodes
Error from server (Timeout): the server was unable to return a response in
the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get nodes)
```

This means the kubernetes cluster is useless if one node goes down, which isn't a great thing.

I'm using Calico/Flannel/canal, nginx-ingress, and metallb.

Comment: Did you shutdown master node or a worker node?

Comment: it's one that is in the `controlplane`, `etc`, and worker. I have ~3 that are HA masters like this.

Comment: How do you advertise you control-plane's endpoint to clients like kubectl ? Seems like your kubectl configuration points to fixed apiserver endpoint, not LoadBalancerIP for K8S in HA mode.